# In the background script for a chrome extension, how does a call to the addListener() method for the chrome.runtime.onInstalled event get processed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, runtime

I'm an absolute beginner in extension development trying to wrap my head around the browser runtime, which consists of the event loop + call stack + web APIs. As I understand it, if you run a script containing a function like this:

```
setTimeout(function msg() {
    console.log("Hey guys.");
}, 4000);
```

The call to `setTimeout()` will be pushed to the call stack, executed, and sent to the Web API which will start the timer for four seconds, after which it pushes the `console.log("Hey guys");` call to the Event Loop queue. It's only until the call stack is empty that this call on the queue is popped, then pushed to the call stack. This callback mechanism is what provides JavaScript engines with asynchronous functionality.

Does the same process apply to the following function call?

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    console.log("Hello");
})
```

Here is where my confusion lies:

1. Assuming `addListener()` is pushed to the call stack, what happens after it's executed? Does the browser now "store" this listener function so that it knows to look out for the `onInstalled` event? And will it push the callback function onto the Event Loop queue once the event has been detected?
2. Why is the `addListener`method called on the event object `chrome.runtime.onInstalled`as opposed to taking it as a parameter?
3. Is the `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` object just a representation of the actual browser event, not the event itself? (i.e. an object provided by the Chrome API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the same process apply to the following function call?

Kind of.

> Assuming addListener() is pushed to the call stack, what happens after it's executed?

When the script starts, addListener adds the listener to the internal event registry without calling it. The registry is keyed on function reference so it'll be registered just once per event i.e. subsequent addListener calls will be effectively ignored.

Then the script ends, all listeners are registered.

Then, in case this script is the non-persistent background script (service worker or an event page), the event that woke the background script will be used to find its registered listeners in the registry and they will be called. This is why the documentation says that API listeners must be registered in "top level", although it's an oversimplification. Technically, the listeners must be registered before the script ends, i.e. it may happen inside a nested function as long as it runs synchronously, and even inside a [synchronously imported ES module](/q/66408379).

> Why is the addListener method called on the event object

This is how the extensions API is implemented internally, there's no universal reason why this exact shape was used, it's just how they liked it and it makes perfect sense because the object contains various useful methods like `hasListener`, `removeListener`, and [several others](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/events/#event-objects).

> Is the chrome.runtime.onInstalled object just a representation of the actual browser event, not the event itself?

The word "event" here doesn't mean an instance of the event similar to DOM `Event` object that is dispatched to JS code. There's no such thing in the extensions API. It's just a static part of the API that is nested to represent the structure thereof: `chrome` is the common namespace, `runtime` is the specific API, `onInstalled` is the event name. This object is constructed by the internal JS layer of the extensions platform when the script starts.

Comment: My knowledge on this is very shaky -- but where is this registry? On the browser itself? And when the listener is called, is it directly pushed onto the callstack from the API or is it queued up on the event loop queue before it gets pushed to the call stack?

Comment: 1) The registry is internal, it's in the browser because everything runs in the browser. 2) When something is called it means it is pushed on the callstack. This is what a callstack means. Registering a listener here or in setTimeout doesn't push the listener on the callstack, it only registers the listener in the internal registry, from which later the listener is called and then it is pushed on the callstack. Note that the callstack shown in devtools combines this internal registry of asynchronous listeners with the the real callstack which is always linear and synchronous.